# Vue - watch for changes on this.$el.clientWidth

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to watch for changes on components element clientWidth (this.$el.clientWidth)?
Something like:

```
 this.$watch(
        () => {
            return this.$el.clientWidth;
        },
        (newWidth, oldWidth) => {
            console.log(newWidth);
        }
    )
```

Comment: imho, there is no way to get an event when an element is resized. If the element would only change its dimension when the window is resized then you could listen on that event. Or you need to check the size on regular intervals. Why do you need to know that? Maybe it is an issue that can resolved with pure css.

Comment: I want to resize fixed element when some other element resizes, no way you can do it with css.

Comment: That would be a good answer, @t.niese

Comment: Intervals are solution, but i hope there is some better way of doing it

Comment: What causes the other element to resize?

Comment: way too many things, cant really trigger event on all these changes

Comment: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-watch-the-height-change-dom-of-an-element-in-vuejs/21290/15

This seams like solution, have to check it a bit better

Comment: Possibly [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) would be useful. Also possibly the [componentUpdated hook of a directive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Hook-Functions)

Comment: tried Mutation Observer, doesnt work in all cases :/

Comment: checking componentUpdated

Answer (score 1):

I am investigating the same problem.
I think the solution dependent on the HTML lifecycle is effective in some cases.
I am pleased if my solution at the present stage will serve you.

```
mousemove (e) {
    this.clientWidth = this.$el.clientWidth
}
```